# NGINX reverse proxy for apps listening on different ports

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have three containers - an NGINX reverse proxy and two web apps. All three are in docker containers. This seems like it ought to be about the simplest use case possible, but I cannot get it to work.

I've put all three containers on a user-defined network and mapped the ports on which the server is listening (8080 for the proxy, 54401 for app1, 54402 for app2). Each server shows a dummy page identifying itself and I can hit and view all three directly (at `http://localhost:8080`, `http://localhost:54401` and `http://localhost:54402`).

I would expect to be able to view the app1 and app2 pages at `http://localhost:8080/app1` and `http://localhost:8080/app2`. However, if I attempt to visit i.e. `http://localhost:8080/app1` I am redirected to `http://localhost/app1` and shown a 404 error. Ditto for app2.

There are no errors in the NGINX logs.

I've looked through several tutorials and trolled the documentation pretty thoroughly. What am I missing?

My default.conf for the proxy:

```
upstream app1 {
    server app1:54401;
}

upstream app2 {
    server app2:54402;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /app1/ {
        proxy_pass http://app1/;
    }

    location /app2/ {
        proxy_pass http://app2/;
    }
}
```

For my 1st app:

```
server {
    listen       54401;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

For my 2nd app:

```
server {
    listen       54402;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

My compose file (for completeness):

```
services:
  app1:
    image: docker.io/nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: app1
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./app1/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./app1/config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - "54401:54401"
    networks:
      - test_network

  app2:
    image: docker.io/nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: app2
    volumes:
      - ./app2/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./app2/config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - "54402:54402"
    networks:
      - test_network

  proxy:
    image: docker.io/nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: proxy
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./proxy/config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./proxy/logs:/var/log/nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - test_network

networks:
  test_network: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the solution, but I think it will help.

```
http {

    sendfile on;

    server {
    listen 80;        
    server_name localhost;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.html;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    # proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;       
  
  
    }

    location /app1/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:54401/;
        
    }
  location /app2/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:54402/;
        
    }
}
}
```

You can find more information [DOCKER COMPOSE: NGINX REVERSE PROXY WITH MULTIPLE CONTAINERS](https://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/Docker/Docker-Compose-Nginx-Reverse-Proxy-Multiple-Containers.php) and [Nginx reverse proxy across multiple back end servers](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/develop-a-website-with-different-frontend-and-api-backend-endpoints/).

Update nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://app1:54401/;
    }
}
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://app2:54402/;
    }
}
```

Comment: On the NGINX container, there's nothing listening on ports 54401 and 54402, so passing to //localhost:54401 and //localhost:54402 won't do anything.

Comment: I'm not sure but you should check out docker-compose.yml.